# Why do colors in my color scale for choropleth map repeat and how to fix it?

Tags: python, plotly-python, colorbar, color-scheme, choropleth

I am making a choropleth map out of a data frame containing state names and most popular car
makes per each state. For some reason, when I assign the make column as a color,
at some point (after GMC) the colors start repeating. How do I make them unique for each make?

(piggybacking to my own question, if someone knows how to save this choropleth map as a jpeg
without using kaleido or savefig, I would really appreciate if you shared the knowledge,
savefig didn't work for me and kaleido takes forever and never finishes)

```
db_map2 = pd.merge(db_pop_makes_states,states_list,on='STATE').reset_index(drop=True)
locations = db_map2['Code'].tolist()
values = db_map2['VEHICLE_MAKER'].tolist()
px.choropleth(locations=locations, locationmode="USA-states", color=values, scope="usa",
    labels={'locations':'State','color':'Makes'},title='NUMBER OF CUSTOMERS PER STATE')
```

[image: Colors start repeating after GMC]

Comment: I can help if I have the data, but it would be easiest to create a color list by manufacturer and add the color columns to an existing data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `color_discrete_sequence` keyword argument to override the sequence of colors used. See the `px.choropleth` [docs](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.html#plotly.express.choropleth) for more details.

You can either use one of the [builtin color sequences](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express) or make up your own.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up adding "color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet" to the choropleth properties and it worked. Default qualitative color scheme from Plotly didn't have enough colors so they repeated. I also view the map using Dash and can download a good image from there.